# Visual Studio Nuget Update - Access denied to \packages\System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.4.3.2\.signature.p7s is denied

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

Hi currently getting the above error when trying to restore or update packages via Nuget on VS2019 16.8.2.

The project was built on anothe rmachine then moved to a new machice, and im guessing its a permissions over the file issue, however, i have given full access to the files and still recive the error?

Any ideas, i have searched a lot on the topic but cant find anything that sorts the issue out?

Comment: Hi, any update about this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these:

**1)** make sure that your OS account can access your solution folder

**2)** [clean all nuget caches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) or delete all cache files under `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages`.

**3)** Close VS Instance, delete the `packages` folder under your solution folder

**4)** run VS as **Administrator** and then reopen your project. run `update-package -reinstall` under **Tools**-->**Nuget Package Manager**--> **Package Manager Console**

Then, rebuild your project again.

Comment: Thanks for this, Yes this worked. The other solution i found was to copy the project directory, deleted the files which had accessed denied< rebuilt the project and updated the older references.

Answer (score 0):

I just:

```
1 - deleted the folder and 
2 - reopen visual studio and it worked fine.
```